# Is it possible to return $var1 & $var2 in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Let's say in my model, I have a function queries and variable array. I need to pass variable $m to the results back to my controller to display in my view.

**Model**

```
  for($i=1; $i<=12;)
    {
     $month=array("","01","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12");
    $m = $month[$i];
    $query2=$this->db->query("
        SELECT 
          COUNT(*) AS rr 
        FROM
          trans_email 
        WHERE lup LIKE '2014-$m%' 
        ");
    $resultarray[$i]=$query2->result();
    foreach($resultarray[$i] as $row)
            {
              $data[$i] = $row;
            }
             $i++;


    }
    return $data;
```

**Controller**

```
$this->load->model('dash_model');
$ind = $this->dash_model->monthreport();
 $data= array();
 $data['mont'] = $ind;  
 $this->parser->parse('blank.htm', $data);
```

**View**

```
{mont}
{rr}
{/mont}
```

Output array $data

```
 [mont] => Array
    (
        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [rr] => 1
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [rr] => 0
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [rr] => 0
            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [rr] => 0
            )

        [5] => stdClass Object
            (
                [rr] => 0
            )

        [6] => stdClass Object
            (
                [rr] => 0
            )

        [7] => stdClass Object
            (
                [rr] => 0
            )

        [8] => stdClass Object
            (
                [rr] => 0
            )

        [9] => stdClass Object
            (
                [rr] => 0
            )

        [10] => stdClass Object
            (
                [rr] => 4
            )

        [11] => stdClass Object
            (
                [rr] => 9
            )

        [12] => stdClass Object
            (
                [rr] => 0
            )
```

how i return var $m to controller to get value 1 - 12 ?

Comment: You have greater issues. For a start your inner loop overwrites its self

Comment: You really need to explain exactly what you are trying to do here

Comment: Do you need to change anything? The current data array will be indexed by month, so you already have the data. `$data[1]` will be the data for january. How exactly do you intend to use this month information? As it stands there is not enough information to answer this question

Comment: @Steve I want to graph the annual report, I need the value of the variable $ m to provide labels on my chart, check my controller and view if you need

Comment: @Steve yes, I have to get the index of $ data [1] for the month of January, the question is, how can I pull out the value of 1-12 of the array variable to the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take both the variables into an array `$my_data_array` and return it like

```
for($i=1; $i<=12;)
{
   $month=array("","01","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12");
   $m = $month[$i];
   $query2=$this->db->query("
    SELECT 
      COUNT(*) AS rr 
    FROM
      trans_email 
    WHERE lup LIKE '2014-$m%' 
    ");
   $resultarray[$i]=$query2->result();
   foreach($resultarray[$i] as $row)
   {
       $data[$i] = $row;
   }
   $i++;
}
$my_data_array['month'] = $m;
$my_data_array['data'] = $data;
return $my_data_array;
```

Comment: i got this error
 `A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Object of class stdClass to string conversion

Filename: libraries/Parser.php`

Comment: `$data` is an array or is it object based?

Comment: `$my_data_array['month']` will always equal `"12"`

Comment: `$data` is an array, because I need to loop on the query `$data[$i]`

Comment: @Steve ya, I was confused to return var $m to controller, to get value 1 - 12

Comment: @Gautam3164 i don't know, i didn't have reputation to vote down